# Am I using IEnumerable correctly?

Tags: c#

I am having a headache with the following code. Seems very straight forward, but I can't get why it is going wrong.

The idea is simple, I am just looping to add a reference of DataGirdView to the ViewModel's property. That's all.

But after I modified the value in ViewModel, `IEnumerable<ICompanyViewModel> vms` would not reflect it as if it didn't happen. What have I done wrong? Please help.

```
    public void UpdateCompany(IEnumerable<ICompanyViewModel> vms) {
        CompanyBindingSource.DataSource = new BindingListView<CompanyViewModel>(vms.ToList());
        var lst = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in DataGridView1.Rows) lst.Add(dgvr);
        foreach (var vm1 in vms) { 
            foreach (var dgvr in lst) {
                var ov = (ObjectView<CompanyViewModel>)dgvr.DataBoundItem;
                var vm2 = (ExhibitorViewModel)ov.Object;
                if (vm1.ID == vm2.ID) {
                    vm1.DataGridViewRow = dgvr;
                    break;
                }
            }                
            if (vm1.DataGridViewRow != null) lst.Remove(vm1.DataGridViewRow); 

        } // I can see DataGridViewRows being matched with vm1.
    }     // Then, I expand IEnumerable 'vms' and check the value again. All
          // the ViewModels lost their references to the matching DataGridViewRows.
          // In every ViewModel.DataGridViewRow = null; WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?? 


//.... here is the background code of my model

public class CompanyViewModel : BaseViewModel, ICompanyViewModel {
    public DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow { get; set; }
    public ICompany Company { get; set; }
    public long ID {
        get { return Company.ID; }
    }
    public string Name {
        get { return Company.Name; }
        set { Company.Name = value; }
    }
}    
public interface ICompanyViewModel : IViewModel {
    DataGridViewRow DataGridViewRow { get; set; }
    public ICompany Company { get; set; }
    long ID { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public interface IViewModel { }
public abstract class BaseViewModel : IViewModel { }
```

Comment: Did you try commenting out this line : `if (vm1.DataGridViewRow != null) lst.Remove(vm1.DataGridViewRow);` just t osee if it works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root of the issue: Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable

I am using the IEnumerable incorrectly. According to Resharper I should really call .ToList(); as soon as I got the list of IEnumerable < ICompanyViewModel > vms.

Otherwise, everytime I call foreach ... I am effectively calling the database again! Omg it is very important not to make mistake on this, lucky I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using `IEnumerable<T>` you have to manually (explicitly) say to binding mechanism (whatever it is), update !.

If you don't like that idea, consider of using [ObservableColelction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead. 
In this case, `.net framework` itself kepp track of `Add` and `Remove` events happened in that collection and updates the binding it was binded to.